# Update column with a lot of values

Tags: excel, csv

I have a spreadsheet with 4000 rows. Each with a unique product name. I have another spreadsheet with 300 rows, with updated prices for some of the products. Is there an easy way to show the updated values side by side, and then use the updates. Finally removing the old values (not having some kind of update column hanging around) (before we've always ended up needing to copy paste into notepad to get the actual values out.)

Comment: Can you give us an example, maybe with some pictures? As it stands it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: eg<br/>
<br/>
Existing CSV<br/>
<br/>
100,abc<br/>
200,daf<br/>
100,ddd<br/>
100,fsdf<br/>
100,hello<br/>
<br/>
new CSV:<br/>
<br/>
10,ddd<br/>
20,daf<br/>

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of example that is, but it makes no sense to me. What column are your unique product names in, what column are their old values in, what sheet has the 300 rows of updated prices, what columns are the product names in there, what columns are your updated prices in there. Those are the things I/we need to help you. I can't read your mind.

Comment: `code` hello, it is a CSV file. But the page seems to be formatting it badly. Do you know how to change that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need - Of course, I can't correctly set it up because I don't know where your columns are or what your sheet names are.

```
For i = 1 to 4000
    For j = 1 to 300
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = _
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j).Value Then
               Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = _
               Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. How can I use this programming language in a spreadsheet?  I was thinking about VLOOKUP myself.